# Do you explicitly identify inclusion in sql table records or is the record itself the identifier?

Tags: mysql

I'm defining a table to show what "groups" a user belongs to.  When creating records in this table, is it better to use a record to identify a user's inclusion in this group or should there be a column that specifies a user's inclusion?

Option 1

```
USER_ID | GROUP_ID
USER001 | GROUP001
USER002 | GROUP001
USER002 | GROUP002
```

Option 2

```
USER_ID | GROUP_ID | MEMBER
USER001 | GROUP001 | YES
USER001 | GROUP002 | NO
USER002 | GROUP001 | YES
USER002 | GROUP002 | YES
```

What is better?  Both imply that `USER001` only belongs to `GROUP001` and not `GROUP002` but it is only known since there is no record of him in `GROUP002` in the first table.  The second table identifies all groups the user could be apart of and clearly states yes or no.

Comment: Consider what should happen when `GROUP003` is added.  Do we want to require that rows be added to the membership table with MEMBER='NO' for *every* user? Both designs are workable, but it seems like the first approach would be a more straightforward design, in terms of maintaining data consistency. (Is the existence of the (USER__1, GROUP__2) row in Option 2 optional or mandatory?)  (Personally, I would go with option 1, with just the existence of the row indicating membership, the absence of a row indicates non-membership.)

Comment: Regarding your first question, I never thought of it that way.  My answer would be I'd prefer to not have to add rows for every user just because I added another group.  That said, I'm not an sql developer but I'm trying to create a scope of work document for a developer I'm working with and want to try to use best practices.

Comment: BTW Thanks for your response.

Comment: Regarding your second question, I think it would be optional.  The groups are going to be used in two ways.  First to identify a user's access to certain parts of the application and secondly as a means for identifying lists of people to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

Your first option is called a join-table or many-to-many relationship table. It's a very common and lightweight way to specify the kind of user - to - group relationship you want. It has the wonderful attribute that its primary key can consist of both columns. That means a user cannot be associated with a group more than once in a way that's enforced by the database.

Your second option also works. But it's harder to maintain consistency, and the queries are more complex because you have to filter by `member='yes'` whenever you want to get lists of memberships.  That can slow your queries down a lot. (I learned this the hard way.)

Go for your first choice: the presence of the record in the join table signifies membership.

Answer (score 0):

Permission systems usually have a default allow or a default deny rule. There are a few reasons why it's a good idea to do that.

1) It reduces the impact of bugs in your security system.

2) it reduces the amount of data you need to store, and reduces the complexity of the queries to read and write data.

choose your first choice, it's simpler, and simple is always key.